# When does Angular create component instances

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am new to angular, From the documentation i learned that we can launch the angular app by the bootstrap the `root` module, then angular can launch the app by creating an instance of `app component` and find the `selector` of this component in  `index.html` and put the view of  that root component, 
My question is whether angular use this same strategy for all components, 
for example does this create all the components same time or create components based  directives declared  on template.

> 1) i have 2 components such as `app component`, `navbar component` 
>     2) app component have `<app-navbar></app-navbar> on its template`

From my understanding 
Angular first create `root component` and paste that component view in the `root component selector(app-root)` on `index.html` , if that root component view has another selector called `app-navbar` then only it create instance of navbar.component and paste that view in selector.correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... and find the selector of this component in  index.html and put the
>   view of that root component

This only happens for components defined as `bootstrap` components in a module decorator. Hence here:

> Angular first create root component

it's better to use term `bootstrap` component as there can be many bootstrap components.

> i have 2 components such as app component, navbar component

Angular compiler will generate two factories. During that process it will encounter `<app-navbar></app-navbar>` and create appropriate view nodes. When Angular will be creating views it will create a view for `navbar component` and instantiate `NavbarComponent` class.

To know more about View start with the [Here is why you will not find components inside Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-why-you-will-not-find-components-inside-angular-bdaf204d955c#4e19)

Comment: from your answer,   other than `bootstrap components` angular will create components only if it finds it respective `selectors`, from my example angular wont create the instance `navbar component` until it finds `<app-navbar>`. correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

Angular will only instantiate a component

1. It encounters a selector for that component
2. If the component is provided in `entryComponent` array
3. If component included in route definition